# How can I put an unexpanded variable in a configuration snippet in the manifest file of a VS Code debugger extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I want to add a configuration snippet (configurationSnippets) while contributing a debugger for a VS Code extension. However, I am unable to include a variable defined as ${command:debugger.getPaths} within the configuration snippet. A simple example showing the problem is as follows:

```json
"configurationSnippets": [
    {
        "label": "Tester Debug Snippet (Launch)",
        "description": "Test config",
        "body": {
            "name": "Test Debug (Launch)",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${command:debugger.getPaths}",
        }
    }
]
```

When using this config snippet, it leads to the following value of program: `"program": "debugger.debugger.getPaths"`. But I would expect this to be instead `"program": "${command:debugger.getPaths}"`.

I have tried a number of escaping strategies like `"\\${command:debugger.getPaths}"`, `"\\$\\{command:debugger.getPaths\\}"`, `"$${command:debugger.getPaths}"`, `"$$\\{command:debugger.getPaths\\}"`. However, none of those achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it like `"program": "^\"\\${command:debugger.getPaths}\""`

Courtesy of [an unexplained example in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/debugger-extension#anatomy-of-the-package.json-of-a-debugger-extension) (`"program": "^\"\\${workspaceFolder}/${1:Program}\""`) and this github issue: 
[configurationSnippet using ${workspaceFolder}
#133614](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133614)- in particular, [this comment in the thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133614#issuecomment-938257121), which I found by googling "`github vscode issues extension "configurationsnippets" command variable`". Funnily (and sadly), people in that thread don't seem to know why it works.

Also possibly related: [DebugConfigurationProvider: provide snippets for launch.json
#34668](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34668).

Also, it's interesting that what you tried with `\\$` didn't work, since that appears to be [the publicly documented solution](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_how-do-i-have-a-snippet-place-a-variable-in-the-pasted-script).

This answer post is linked to in this issue ticket: [Variables within a configuration snippet defined in package.json file are not being allowed #176795](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176795). [Looks like we almost got an explanation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176795#issuecomment-1566703940), but [apparently not](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176795#issuecomment-1566711104).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A slight issue in the answer, this actually works (though the reasoning is not clear as you also mentioned): "program": "^\"\\${command:debugger.getPaths}\"", as taken from https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/debugger-extension#anatomy-of-the-package.json-of-a-debugger-extension. If you can edit your answer and fix this, I will accept this as the correct one.